# Passing a file as an input to shell script through python

Tags: python-3.x, bash, aws-lambda

I have a python program, which calls the shell script through subprocess() module. I am looking for a way to pass a simple file, as an input to shell script. Does this happen through subproess and popen?

I have tried this code for an AWS lambda function

Comment: please show what you tried and the correct way to call the script (from shell)

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice/helpful if you could share some excerpt of your code in your question.

But assuming bits of it.

Here is a way to achieve this.

```
import shlex
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen

import logger

def run_script(script_path, script_args):
    """
    This function will run a shell script.
    :param script_path: String: the path of script that needs to be called
    :param script_args: String: the arguments needed by the shell script
    :return:
    """
    logger.info("Running bash script {script} with parameters:{params}".format(script=script_path, params=script_args))

   # Adding a whitespace in shlex.split because the path gets distorted if args are added without it
   session = Popen(shlex.split(script_path + " " + script_args), stderr=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, shell=False)
   stdout, stderr = session.communicate()

   # Beware that stdout and stderr will be bytes so in order to get a proper python string decode the values.
   logger.debug(stdout.decode('utf-8'))

   if stderr:
       logger.error(stderr)
       raise Exception("Error " + stderr.decode('utf-8'))

   return True
```

Now a couple of things to note here

- Your bash script should be able to handle the args properly may it be `$1` or named params like `--file` or `-f`
- Just give all the params you want in the string array in `shlex` method.
- Also note the comments mentioned in code above.